# Why do we omit preposition before 'these days'?

Tags: prepositions

We usually say 'in those days'. Eg: In those days, his life was miserable. 
When we say 'these days', usually,  we don't use preposition before it. 
Eg: These days he is very busy.
Can anyone explain accurately where we need to use preposition and where we need not.

Comment: In any language, phrases that are used very frequently are the ones that evolve/change fastest. Time phrases are very common and thus they change quicker. Thus, we have the word “tomorrow” that is comprised of the preposition “to” and the noun “morrow” (meaning “morning”.) We also have such phrases as “Here are the tablets – take three a day,” in which “a day” is a variant of “of days” or “on/at [the] day”. So, the answer to your question is, “Because that’s what we say.”

Comment: The choice and use of prepositions, including where they can or should be omitted, is highly idiomatic in English. We are talking about fixed expressions established over many years. They defy logical explanation. So the answer to your question, *“Can anyone explain...?”* is ‘no’.

Answer (score 0):

In formal writing or speech, there would be a preposition. "These days" is an abbreviated version of "in these days." A more formal way of saying this would be "Currently" or "In the present period of time." 
As for why we shorten it, there are several reasons. People abbreviate sentences when speaking to one another. Sometimes this is done out of ignorance of the proper way to phrase a sentence. Other times it may just be to save time when speaking. As time goes on and people hear others use a phrase, they adopt it themselves, and what was once an odd turn of phrase becomes common and sometimes even grammatically correct.